# ActiveAdmin Rails 4 NoMenuError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using the Rails 4 branch of ActiveAdmin.

I have a Location model that is excluded from the menu via:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do

  belongs_to :area

  menu false
end
```

The Area model is NOT excluded from the menu.

When I try to create a new location in a test such as by:

```
post :create, location: { "name" => "Sorry"}, area_id: a.id
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
ActiveAdmin::MenuCollection::NoMenuError: No menu by the name of :area in availble (sic)
menus: default, utility_navigation, season
```

When I add the locations back to the menu (i.e. comment out 'menu false')..the problem goes away.  I did not have this problem pre-Rails 4.

Obviously I would rather be able to keep using the method to exclude from the menu rather than css.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting this too in 0.6.2

Answer (score 5):

Just remove "menu false", it doesn't work with belongs_to

Answer (score 4):

try this, worked for me...

```
ActiveAdmin.register Location do

  belongs_to :area

  **menu :if => proc{false}**

end
```